# How to print something in python which matches object in the list

Tags: python, sockets

I'm very new to programming and my first language is Python.  I'm printing a list of IP addresses:

```
import socket
dandanakka = ["madrasdeals.com","google.com","yahoo.com"]
for i in dandanakka:

    ip = socket.gethostbyname(i)

    print ip
```

The result is okay:

```
139.59.1.111
172.217.26.174
98.138.253.109
```

Is there any way to print my results to the matching domain name?

Like 
    google.com - 172.217.26.174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple: you already have that in variable `i`:

```
import socket
dandanakka = ["madrasdeals.com","google.com","yahoo.com"]
for i in dandanakka:

    ip = socket.gethostbyname(i)
    print i, " - ", ip
```

Answer (score 0):

Append your variables to the string. Put this within your for:
`print('{domain} - {ip}'.format(domain=i, ip=ip))`

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over your list and print both the value and the result of `socket.gethostbyname()`:

```
for i in dandanakka:
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(i)
    print("{} - {}".format(i, ip))
```